# require_once is not working inside function

Tags: php, mysql

I have got two functions which retrieve values from a database. When I access the connection (`$connection`) inside function I am unable to access the DB. I am using mysql+PHP

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
<?php
function getTierOne()
{
    require_once('../config.php');
    $provincequery="SELECT provinces.ProvinceID, provinces.ProvinceName FROM provinces WHERE ProvinceID > 0";
      $result = $connection->query($provincequery);
      while($province = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
           echo '<option value="'.$province['ProvinceID'].'">'.$province['ProvinceName'].'</option>';
        }

}

//**************************************
//     First selection results     //
//**************************************
if(isset($_GET['func'])  &&  $_GET['func'] == "province") 
{
   province($_GET['drop_var']); 
}

function province($drop_var)
{  
    require_once('../config.php');

    $district_query = "SELECT  districts.DistrictID, districts.DistrictName, provinces.ProvinceName FROM districts, provinces WHERE                        provinces.ProvinceID=districts.ProvinceID AND districts.DistrictID > 0 AND provinces.ProvinceID='$drop_var'";

    $district_query_run= $connection->query($district_query);
    echo '<select name="district" id="district" style="width:150px;">
          <option value="0" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Your District</option>';

           while($district= $district_query_run->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$district['DistrictID'].'">'.$district['DistrictName'].'</option>';
            }

    echo '</select>';
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$('#wait_2').hide();
    $('#district').change(function(){
      $('#wait_2').show();
      $('#result_2').hide();
      $.get(\"ProDisPds/func.php\", {
        func: \"district\",
        drop_var: $('#district').val()
      }, function(response){
        $('#result_2').fadeOut();
        setTimeout(\"finishAjax_tier_three('result_2', '\"+escape(response)+\"')\", 400);
      });
        return false;
    });
</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: It is not very clear what isn't working. Can you describe better what the problem is (error message, expected behaviour vs actual behaviour, ...)

Comment: If your require is not working, PHP will show an error message. Put `error_reporting(-1);` at the beginning of your function. This turns the error reporting on.

Comment: sorry for late reply i am not receiving any error massage i am receiving white screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider not requiring inside of those functions, it would make more sense to pass an argument to those functions which are a reference to the database connection.

So do

```
require_once('../config.php');
```

Before you call the functions that use the function, it is more practical and less overhead when it comes to requiring a lot of times when you could do it just once.

You should show us config.php since It's the source of the connection but let's assume that

```
$connection
```

is defined inside of config.php, well, use [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if($isset($connection))
```

Nevertheless, you can't be sure whether It's set or not. If It's not set then you can access the database connection function, which I assume you made inside of config, to create a new connection.

The [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a) might be useful here:

```
$connection = if(isset($connection)) ? $connection : newConnection();
```

If this isn't working, and this is a school project or something similar, then you could try defining the connection as a global variable that can be accessed within your file, so you could do something like this inside of config.php

```
$GLOBALS['connection'] = connect(); // Or $connection or whatever the function name was.
```

So you can do something like this

```
require_once('../config.php');
$connection = $GLOBALS['connection'];
```

inside of the file which needs the connection.

But using global variables is risky and shouldn't be used unless you've tried everything else.

I'd be glad to give you more useful tips if you show us the config file and the entire code that is related.

Two more things: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), use [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), and don't mix JavaScript and PHP together.

Comment: long answer my ENGLISH is not good please make it simple or edit my code

Comment: @DawoodNazari Welcome to SO! We're not a demanding community, so please refrain from making demands of a user who has helped you by providing an excellently detailed answer. It's your job as the OP to take time to understand the poster's answer and post comments if you have any specific questions. Thanks!

Comment: okay here is the config.php page code   <?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root"; 
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "a8439146_spdeal";

$connection = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass, $db_name);
?>