# Fatal error: Class 'Client' not found in

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, twilio

I got an error while adding Twilio SMS APi to my website. My site is in wordpress and using Woo commerce.

Error : **`Fatal error: Class 'Client' not found in /var/www/html/++++/wp-content/themes/dokan-theme-v2.2.2-child/functions.php on line 4583`**

My code is below:

```
function wl8OrderPlacedTriggerSomething($order_id){
      //do something...

      //echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Client.php';

      require_once( get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php');
      require( get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Client.php');

        // Use the REST API Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
     // use Twilio\Rest\Client;

        // Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
        $sid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $client = new Client($sid, $token);

        // Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!
        $client->messages->create(
            // the number you'd like to send the message to  (xxxxxxx)
            'xxxxxxxxx',
            array(
                // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
                'from' => '+xxxxxxx',
                // the body of the text message you'd like to send
                'body' => "Hey Jenny! Good luck on the bar exam!"
            )
        );

}
```

Please help me for the same.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think you may need to use the fully qualified namespace for the `Client` in this case. Try:

```
$client = new Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);
```

Let me know if that helps.

**Edit**

OK, that didn't work. After reading around, I've found that [it's not recommended to use `require` or `require_once` within a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381291/require-once-is-not-working-inside-function). I'd recommend you require the autoload file outside of your function, `use` the namespace and then call the `Client` inside the function. Like this:

```
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php');
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

function wl8OrderPlacedTriggerSomething($order_id){

    $sid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $client = new Client($sid, $token);

    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for reply, let me check.

Comment: Same error Fatal error: Class 'Twilio\Rest\Client' not found in /var/www/html/===/dev/wp-content/themes/dokan-theme-v2.2.2-child/functions.php on line 4582

Comment: I've updated my answer with another idea, take a look and see if it works

Comment: i got this error now please have a look

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twilio\Exceptions\RestException' with message '[HTTP 400] Unable to create record: The From phone number +xxxxxxxxxxxxx is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account.' in /var/www/html/mealteck/dev/wp-content/themes/dokan-theme-v2.2.2-child/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Version.php:85 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/mealteck/dev/wp-content/themes/dokan-theme-v2.2.2-child/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Version.php(207):

Comment: Twilio\Version->exception(Object(Twilio\Http\Response), 'Unable to creat...') #1 /var/www/html/mealteck/dev/wp-content/themes/dokan-theme-v2.2.2-child/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/MessageList.php(65): Twilio\Version->create('POST', '/Accounts/AC638...', Array, Array) #2 /var/www/html/mealteck/dev/wp-content/themes/dokan-theme-v2.2.2-child/functions.php(4594): Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\MessageList->create('xxxxxxxxxxxx', Array) #3 [internal function]:

Comment: wl8OrderPlacedTriggerSomething(295) #4 /var/www/html/mealteck/dev/wp-includes/plugin. in /var/www/html/mealteck/dev/wp-content/themes/dokan-theme-v2.2.2-child/twilio-php-master/Twilio/Version.php on line 85

Comment: So, it looks like the `From` number you are trying to send the message from is not capable of doing so. Make sure you are using a Twilio number that you have bought in your account and has SMS capabilities.

Comment: I am using trial version account right now is this is the issue ?

Comment: Not as long as you are using the Twilio number from your account and sending the message to a number you have verified with your account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148044/discussion-between-pardeep-pathania-and-philnash).

Comment: Actually, your first method worked in my custom class. My objective was to instantiate a Twilio client object from within the called function, rather than passing the object along with the rest of the form variables in an ajax request in order to balance the payload a little bit. Also, I don't want to expose the Twilio object as form variables.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that autoload.php and Client.php files are getting loaded properly.
its unable to load client call

Comment: Thank you for reply , yes these are loaded i have echo the file path as well. any other suggestions